# ffmpeg - convert mkv to mp4 with default subtitle

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

What is best way to convert mkv to mp4, with default subtitle (that mkv have), and keep same quality of video / audio ?

Currently I'm using this command

```
ffmpeg -y -i filename.mkv -vf subtitles='filename.mkv' -disposition:s default+forced -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -crf 27 -preset ultrafast filename.mp4
```

But the command still not perfect, the mkv have better quality than mp4 generated. Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: Why is it tagged `PHP`?

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898671/converting-mkv-to-h-264-ffmpeg

Comment: @mega6382 sorry because I'm using ffmpeg via php

Comment: @headmax I have read the suggestions in other topic, but I don't know how still to improve quality

Comment: @Zeta you can try the `-preset xxx` that will calcul bitrate for you, try to find to famous solution depends of your mkv and the size limit you wanted  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Answer (score 0):

your preset is lowest possible quality, and crf could be lower, 18 is more or less lossless, this will make the transcoding slower.  of course
So suggest -crf 18   and -preset slow

If you aren't bothered about which codecs you use you could just copy everything into the mp4 container, which would be megaquick

Comment: If I copu to mp4 it will not add default subtitle hardcoded in mp4.

Comment: regarding crf 18, I tried it, it converted a video with filesize 1GB! which previous command converted it to 400MB only

Comment: size is another tradeoff, increase -crf a little until an acceptable compromise is reached, but definitely keep the preset on slow.. Re subtitles, Could you post your output?